# Play Framwork 2.4 compile error due to build or routing

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

Today, while doing a tutorial with the Play! Framework, I encountered a problem when compiling the source which seemingly has to do with the routing.

I had a friend, a very experienced professional programmer (experienced with Play, too), look into it, and while we were on it, his own personal project showed the same problems when run on Mac OS.

I tried the below steps on my personal machine running Ubuntu 15.10 as well as a Digitalocean Droplet running Fedora 23.

Here are my steps:

1. `activator new`
   (chose "play-java" as template and "shop" as project name.

2.) Added the following "Items.java" into the app/controllers-directory:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.mvc.Results;

public class Items extends Controller {

        static final Shop shop = Shop.Shop;

        public static Result list() {
                return Results.ok();
        }

        public static Result create() {
                return status(NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
        }

        public static Result details(Long id) {
                return status(NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
        }

        public static Result update(Long id) {
                return status(NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
        }

        public static Result delete(Long id) {
                return status(NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
        }

}
```

The conf/routes looks as follows:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET           /                    controllers.Application.index

GET           /items               controllers.Items.list


POST          /items               controllers.Items.create()
GET           /items/:id           controllers.Items.details(id: Long)
PUT           /items/:id           controllers.Items.update(id: Long)
DELETE        /items/:id           controllers.Items.delete(id: Long)


# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET           /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

build.sbt is as follows:

```
name := """shop"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
//routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

If we now run "activator ~run" I get the following errors:

```
[root@sandbox shop]# ./activator ~run
[info] Loading project definition from /root/activator-dist-1.3.6/shop/project
[info] Set current project to shop (in build file:/root/activator-dist-1.3.6/shop/)

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[info] Compiling 6 Scala sources and 3 Java sources to /root/activator-dist-1.3.6/shop/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /root/activator-dist-1.3.6/shop/conf/routes:6: value index is not a member of object controllers.Application
[error] GET           /                    controllers.Application.index
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

We find no way around it and have found no fitting resolution to the problem. Has anybody an idea?

I didn't change anything in the default project except for the 3 files mentioned. Does anyone here have an idea what went wrong?

Comment: Seems like the index function its not part of the Application class. Check first if there is in fact an Application class. In last case just delete the first entry of the routes file and check if it works.

Answer (score 3):

1. Activate this line in your build.sbt:

   ```
   // Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
   // other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
   routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
   ```
2. remove "static" modifier from your methods, e.g.

   ```
   public Result list() {
           return Results.ok();
   }
   ```

For description see:  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24 -> Dependency Injection -> Routing